# How to do port forwarding over Android USB tethering?

Tags: wi-fi, router, usb

So, for the time being I'm stuck plugging my phone into my PC and using USB tethering to connect to Wi-Fi.

One of my games requires port forwarding for online play, and I'm having trouble getting it to connect. I've gone to my router settings and forwarded the appropriate ports from the phone's internal IP address, but still nothing. Here are the ports needed in case it helps:

- DirectPlay7 47624 47624 TCP/UDP
- DirectPlay8 6073 6073 UDP
- DPlay7&8 2300 2400 TCP/UDP
- Outlaws 5310 5310 TCP

I've also been fiddling with Telnet and ADB, but to no effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: Either I'm misunderstanding, or something here is backwards. Port forwarding is done at the router **to** the device, not from the device to the router. Where are you setting up this forwarding? if correctly at the router, you will probably also have to do it again in the PC's connection share.

Comment: Just buy a cheap USB Wifi dongle and directly connect your computer to the Wifi.

Comment: When you use phone in tethering mode, it itself works as a router. So you have to forward ports on phone as well. Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/168422/how-to-port-forward-internet-using-android-hotspot-to-pc/207342#207342

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66564/port-forwarding-during-usb-tethering